CTRL+C Not working to stop spawned node.js process
I have a pair of very simple Node.js applications (both reduced by me to the bare minimum to reproduce the behavior).
The first (app1) spawns a regular CMD shell at a specific drive letter and directory location.
// app1.js
const { spawn } = require('child_process');
spawn('start', ['cmd', '/k', `"D: && cd D:\\SomeFolder"`],  {
    detached: true, 
    stdio: 'ignore',
    shell: true
});

The second, is in the target location ("D:\SomeFolder") and is simply a script to be started by node and keep running for a while. This second script may be literally any node.js code that runs for some seconds.
// app2.js
setTimeout(() => console.log('timed out'), 10000);

When starting app2.js from a regular CMD window, with node app2.js it behaves as normal, and ends when I press CTRL+C, but not when pressing CTRL+BREAK (or CTRL+PAUSE in some keyboards).
But, when started from the shell created by node app1.js, the opposite happens: app2 won't stop with CTRL+C, only with CTRL+BREAK.
I tried to capture the process exiting events on app2, to determine the cause of the problem. I changed app2 to add an event listener for each of the quitting events, and 'SIGBREAK' was triggered but not 'SIGTERM' nor 'SIGINT'.
// app2.js

// Added event listeners for most process-quitting events
['SIGHUP', 'SIGINT', 'SIGQUIT', 'SIGILL', 'SIGTRAP', 'SIGABRT',
 'SIGBUS', 'SIGFPE', 'SIGUSR1', 'SIGSEGV', 'SIGUSR2', 'SIGTERM', 'SIGBREAK'
].forEach(function(element, index, array) {
     process.on(element, function() {
         console.log('Received %s - terminating ...', element);
         process.exit(1);
     });
});

setTimeout(() => console.log('timed out'), 10000);

I know the setTimeout(() => console.log('timed out'), 10000); is not the cause, as I actually tried many code blocks, including: a small Express server, a vanilla HTTP server, a 100000-limited FOR loop, and the behavior was the same in all cases.
I also verified the CMD Properties tab on the spawned window, and everything is exactly the same as in the regular CMD windows.
I believe it may be connected to the way I'm spawning the CMD window. The only thing that may contradict this, is that CTRL+C works on the shell itself, only not in the node.js process.
It is important that the spawned shell can be totally detached from the app1 process.
What is happening there?
Can someone think of a cause for this, or at least a better way to determine the cause?

I don't understand what the goal is, but I found a possibly relevant A on another Ctrl-C Q. Adding this listener to the child causes it to respect Ctrl-C and die, but the window is either left open (because of '/k'; requires manually exiting) or opens and closes in the blink of an eye (without '/k').
